# Shotwell crop-dialog has disappeared

Tags: shotwell

A while ago, I moved the crop-dialog (where you can edit what dimensions you want the crop to be), probably almost out of my screen. Now, whenever I press the crop-button, the dialog is nowhere to be seen, it has disappeared. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I can cause an equivalent problem with kubuntu 18.04 by taking a screen capture, selecting Open from the "Active Window Captured" dialog that pops up, and then attempting to crop.  (Thankfully, the answer below solves the problem for me.)  I guess I'll go look for where to log the bug...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same, resetting the crop settings that Shotwell remembers with `gsettings` fixed it for me:

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.yorba.shotwell.crop-settings
```

Comment: This seems to work on kubuntu 18.04 after losing the crop dialog by opening a screen capture using the tray notification and attempting to crop.  Opening the image from Dolphin then allows me to crop.

Comment: Although this initially seemed to work, in reproducing to log the bug, it seems this did not work consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I just logged a similar issue as https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/shotwell/issues/136.  As I commented on user70550's answer, `gsettings reset-recursively org.yorba.shotwell.crop-settings`
 seemed to work initially to solve my problem, but then did not work consistently when reproducing the issue so that I could log it.

What did work consistently on my kubuntu 18.04 system was to reposition the Shotwell window, after which the crop dialog would pop to the front.

Note: sometimes the crop dialog was in a top corner of my display (sometimes far from the Shotwell window) and sometimes the crop dialog appeared over the image itself.